# Why is NHibernate cascading before executing a query?

Tags: nhibernate

So I'm using the `Nhibernate.Linq` API to run a query. The query itself only takes about 50 ms, but the total time spent by NHibernate to return the result is around 500ms.

The query is something like as follows, `session.Query<T>().Where(i => i.ForeignKey == someValue).Take(5).ToList().AsQueryable()`. And this query executes in less than ~50ms from the debug log of creating the `HQLQueryPlan`, through setting up params, opening the connection, hydrating the C# objects and finishing.

However, before it even began getting that far, the debug log shows that NHibernate spent ~400ms cascading saves and updates, and then reports a bundle of `Collection found:` logs which appear to be `Collection` properties of the objects that I'm asking for. I should add the `ISession` being used is read only, and has absolutely not modified or created any entity. After spending these 400ms, it then logs that it flushed 0 changes.

Why is NHibernate cascading a load of save/update commands during execution of a `.Query<T>()`, is it trying to make sure that the correct data is retrieved? Is this the result of some configuration that I have set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such behavior is possible for queries executed **only** inside transaction and when:

- You have set FlushMode to `FlushMode.Always`
- **Or** NHibernate detected that your query involves tables that are modified in current session. This behaviour can be disabled by setting FlushMode to values less than `FlushMode.Auto` (that's default) (so it's `FlushMode.Commit` or `FlushMode.Manual`)

You can change FlushMode for your session or specify default flush mode in `default_flush_mode` configuration setting. See [spec](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing) for details

Comment: I've set `FlushMode.Never` for this session (it was `FlushMode.Auto` previously), this has solved the flushing problem. However, this session is read-only (which is why I'm fine to set this flush mode) so I'm not sure why NHib did this...Perhaps it's because this session is taking part in a transaction? Although the wrapping transaction is also read-only...It also flushes every time, so if I run the query repeatedly, it takes the full 400ms to flush "nothing" repeatedly...

Comment: `FlushMode.Never` is obsolete in recent versions. You should use `FlushMode.Manual`. Yeah it seems NHibernate should skip auto flush logic for read-only sessions but it doesn't...